# Problems with own AD forms authentication in LS 2011 web application

Tags: authentication, web, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've got a problem with a LightSwitch 2011 web application using forms authentication.

I've implemented my own login screen which authenticates the user against the active directory. My code also checks to see if the user is assigned to a specific active directory group to decide if they can add / edit / delete data.

The login form is placed on the Login.aspx page. The button to login holds the following code:

```
protected void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LdapAuthentication authentication = new LdapAuthentication();

    try
    {
        bool isUserAdmin = false;
        if (authentication.IsUserAuthenticated(textBoxUserName.Text, textBoxPassword.Text, ref isUserAdmin))
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
            textBoxUserName.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1), false, String.Empty);

            //Encrypt the ticket.
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket);

            //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            //If the everyoneAdmin is set to true the validation of the administratorgroup
            //is decativated so we have to grant the current user administrator rights
            if (everyoneAdmin)
                isUserAdmin = true;

            Session["isUserAdmin"] = isUserAdmin ;

            Response.Redirect("default.htm");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        labelError.Text = ex.Message;
        labelError.Visible = true;
        textBoxPassword.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}

public bool IsUserAuthenticated(String userName, String password, ref bool isUserAdmin)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        return false;

    String domain = String.Empty;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"]))
        domain = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"]).Trim();
    else
        throw new NullReferenceException("The Domain in the configuration must not be null!");

    String ldpa = String.Empty;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDPA"]))
        ldpa = String.Format("LDAP://{0}", Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDPA"]).Trim());
    else
        throw new NullReferenceException("The LDPA in the configuration must not be null!");

    String administrationGroup = String.Empty;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdministratorGroup"]))
        administrationGroup = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdministratorGroup"]).Trim();
    else
        throw new NullReferenceException("The AdministrationGroup in the configuration must not be null!");

    String domainUserName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain.Trim(), userName.Trim());
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldpa, domainUserName, password);

    try
    {
        //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
        object obj = directoryEntry.NativeObject;
        DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

        directorySearcher.Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", userName.Trim());
        directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
        SearchResult directorySearchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();

        //unable to find a user with the provided data
        if (directorySearchResult == null)
            return false;

        if (directorySearchResult.Properties["memberof"] != null)
        {
            //If the memberof string contains the specified admin group
            for (int i = 0; i < directorySearchResult.Properties["memberof"].Count; i++)
            {
                string temp = directorySearchResult.Properties["memberof"].ToString();
                // get the group name, for example:
                if (directorySearchResult.Properties["memberof"].ToString().ToLower().Contains(administrationGroup.ToLower()))
                {
                    isUserAdmin = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Error authenticating user.\n\rMessage:\n\r {0}", ex.Message));
    }

    return true;
}
```

**In the class which holds the `CanExcecute` (server tier) methods I've implemented the following method:**

```
public bool IsCurrentUserAdmin()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["isUserAdmin"] == null)
        return false;

    return (bool)(HttpContext.Current.Session["isUserAdmin"]);
}
```

**For example, the `CanExcecute` methods for one table**

```
partial void dtFacilities_CanDelete(ref bool result)
{
    result = this.IsCurrentUserAdmin();
}

partial void dtFacilities_CanInsert(ref bool result)
{
    result = this.IsCurrentUserAdmin();
}

partial void dtFacilities_CanUpdate(ref bool result)
{
    result = this.IsCurrentUserAdmin();
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <form>s name=".ASPXAUTH"
       loginUrl="Login.aspx"
       protection="All"
       timeout="30"
       path="/"
       requireSSL="false"
       slidingExpiration="true"
       defaultUrl="Home.aspx"
       cookieless="UseUri" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?">
</deny></authorization>
```

**Problems**:

1. The problem is that if the user is idle for longer than the `timeout` the session times out. So, the session token `isUserAdmin` is `NULL`. At this point I want the application to return to the login screen. A `Response.Redirect` and a `Server.Transfer` did not work in the `IsCurrentUserAdmin()` method. How can I get the application to return the user to the login screen if the session token `isUserAdmin` is `NULL`?! Remember, the session token is set in the `login.aspx` page code behind
2. When the user closes the final tab of the Lightswitch application, the application opens a new tab and navigates past the login page and they are automatically logged in without processing the login process on the `login.aspx` page. This means that the session token `isUserAdmin` is `NULL`. This happens even if the user has not logged in before they closed the final tab of the application. This leads again to problem 1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, if, for whatever reason, `isUserAdmin` is set to `NULL`, you want to return the user to to the login screen.

In my application, I simply use a button that the user can click to log off. But the underlying method should work just the same in your case.

First create a new page called LogOff.aspx. The page itself, you can leave default generated code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For the code behind, you'll want something like this (please check this, I converted from my project which is in VB):

```
using System.Web.Security;

namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
  public partial class LogOff : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
      Response.Redirect("default.htm");
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code in which I use a button. But if you take the section where the `Dispatcher` calls `Navigate` and place it in your `IsCurrentUserAdmin()` method, it should do the same trick (again, check the C#):

```
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading;
using System.Windows.Browser;

        partial void btnLogOff_Execute()
        {
            Dispatchers.Main.Invoke(() =>
            {
                HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("LogOff.aspx", UriKind.Relative));
            });
        }
```

In my experience, there is a bit of a gotcha in Lightswitch. If you were to execute as is, you would probably receive the following:

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> *The resource cannot be found.*
>
> **Description:** HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> **Requested URL:** /LogOff.aspx

The fix is this:

First right click your project name in Solution Explorer and Unload Project. Once the project is unloaded, right click it and Edit project_name.lsproj. `Ctrl+F` for `default.htm`. You're looking for the section where it is proceeded by `_BuildFile`. Copy that section from `_BuildFile` to `/_BuildFile`, paste below that section and modify as follows.

```
<_BuildFile Include="Server/LogOff.aspx">
  <SubFolder>
  </SubFolder>
  <PublishType>
  </PublishType>
</_BuildFile>
```

Now right click and Reload your project. If you get errors when trying to build, try Build | Clean and build again. If you run the application in Debug, this code will just reload the page. But once you publish and subsequently cause `isUserAdmin` to be `NULL` the code should log you out and take you back to the log on screen.

**References:**

[Original MSDN Forum Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/13b2adcf-aacc-49fb-83b8-7c0c70466a85)

[My experience implementing it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/eebdcafe-b967-43cd-bab8-6b85524f9d05)

Comment: Thanks for your reply  The approach does not work for my implementation.  The problem is that i cant use the HtmlPage.Window.Navigate because i can not reference to System.Windows.Browser. To make it clear, the IsCurrentUserAdmin() method is implemented here (link to a picture to make it clear):  <http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/151376> Maybe my approach is not the right way and i have to re factor it?!

Comment: Maybe my solution is overkill. What if you just call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); Response.Redirect("default.htm");` from `IsCurrentUserAdmin()` or even in the `CanExecute` code itself? That should just require `System.Web.Security` which should be available in the `DataService` code.

Comment: That's what i've tried.. but it takes no effect. The site just loads and does not redirect to the login page.. I don't know why but i think i will avoide ls in the future. :)

Comment: Are you running in debug mode? As I mentioned, that code will just reload the page in debug mode. You need to publish in order for the logout to work properly.

Comment: Also, since your main problem revolves around getting information about a user's group from the Active Directory, try upgrading to the 2012 RC. They added support in the Beta for [Active Directory Groups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2012/04/03/active-directory-group-support-matt-thalman.aspx). Using the built in permissions should be a lot easier than trying to roll your own security.

Comment: Yes i'm running it in the debug mode. I'll try it out tomorrow by publishing the application. I've also thought about using 2012 but as far as i know in LS 2012 Silverlight is not supported anymore and you'll have to switch to HTML5. The company who will use this LS application is still using IE8 because of the company policies or sumthin like that and IE8 is not supporting HTML5 afaik.

Comment: Silverlight is most defiantly supported. HTML5 is an add-on to push Lightswitch into the mobile market. Silverlight is still at the core. [HTML Client Announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2012/06/11/announcing-the-lightswitch-html-client.aspx)

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 is going to RTM on Wednesday, so you won't even have to use the RC version...

Comment: First i'll try it the suggested solution by deploying the application. Maybe the logut works then. If not i'll wait till wednesday and give LS 2012 a try. :)

Comment: Now i've deployed the application, but after my own login the page redirects to default.htm and shows another - probably lightswitch - login screen. I don't know how to deactivated that screen.. i've never seen it before..

Comment: Okay. That's progress. What happens when you change from `Response.Redirect("default.htm")` to `Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")`? `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` should sign out the user if they are logged in. Then the `Redirect` should take you to your custom login page. That's what you are trying to achieve, correct?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i was kinda busy the last week. I've installed the new VS 2012 and i'll give LS 2012 a try with the implemented AD authentication. Maybe it meet my requirements. I'll reply when i have an update on this ;). Thanks so far for the help! :)

Comment: Hey, i like Microsoft. They release such a product like LightSwitch 2012 and i can't find any tutorial, Walkthrough or something like that which explains the active directory authentication in LightSwitch 2012. It seems like that nothing has changed so far from LS 11 -> 12. I still do not see the possibility to realize the following:  - Login page with validating credentials against add  -Check if user is in a specific ad group YES: grant add/edit/delete rights NO: do not grant them  - define that group in web config  - on timeout get the user back to login page

Comment: Next time i'll avoid this piece of crap called LightSwitch and realize the needs of an really SIMPLE administration page with SIMPLE requirements using NHibernate and ASP.NET. Sorry MS but LightSwitch fails at all points of requirements for developing a administration GUI